# Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%=" in ejs route

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I am getting this error when using .ejs routes and it doesn't seem to come from the code but from the ejs pack

```
Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%=".
at E:\...\Main\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:740:19
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Template.generateSource (E:\...\Main\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:730:15)
at Template.compile (E:\...\Main\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:585:12)
at Object.compile (E:\...\Main\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:396:16)
at handleCache (E:\...\Main\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:233:18)
at tryHandleCache (E:\...\Main\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:16)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (E:\...\Main\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
at View.render (E:\...\Main\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
at tryRender (E:\...\Main\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
```

I tried checking where the error occured but it is not very clear to me as I am new to coding.
If it can help, here is where I use the <%= %>

```
    <img src="<%= profile.data[0].stats.rank.metadata.iconUrl %>" alt="<%= profile.data[0].stats.rank.metadata.tierName %>" style="height:4rem;width:4rem;margin-right:.5rem;">
<div>
  <span class="valorant-highlighted-stat__label">
    <%= profile.data[0].stats.rank.displayName %>
  </span><br>
  <span class="valorant-highlighted-stat__value">
    <%= profile.data[0].stats.rank.metadata.tierName %>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there anywhere else you're using EJS tags?

Comment: I think these EJS tags are closed, maybe EJS tags somewhere else on the code? Specifically at line 740

Comment: line 740 doesnt exist in the code, its in the ejs.js module and every tag is the same format i checked 10 times

Comment: Remove all content of your `ejs` file then try again.

Comment: I'd update your post with the whole page content as it must be elsewhere in that page where a tag is missing

Answer (score 0):

try `<%- profile.data[0].stats.rank.displayName %>` - instead of =

Comment: Please post this as a comment, or explain why this would solve the problem.